# Is it possible to ping/check if website exists and works?

Tags: java, android

Well i guess title says pretty much everything, i want to generate random website adress, but i need to check if that website exists as well. So is there a way on android/java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the response code like this:

```
URL url = new URL("Your URL");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
// if Website is ok this wil be called
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at `InetAddress` package, there are plenty different ways to achieve this.

```
private boolean exists(String host){
   try{

    InetAddress.getByName(host);
    return true;
   }catch(UnknowHostException e){
     return false;
   }
}
```